Docking station - 2x (or 3x) 4K@60Hz, stable drivers
Current situation
I have two docking stations that I have problems with  (one at home, one at work). One is an I-Tec, which has some features not working... and the other one is a Lenovo, which has features not working, features working that randomly stop working, drivers issues requiring frequent uninstallation... I had to give up using any external monitor through both docking stations... but then I could have used cheaper devices.
Request
I would like recommandations for a docking station model with the following criteria:
Required

Stable drivers and operation
Not requiring "not to use some features" to have other features work (otherwise, what's the point of docking station)?
2 (or 3) x 4K@60Hz external monitor, preferably HDMI
Not using DisplayLink
Ethernet port
USB-C in front
Flat or vertical shape (so not a square or star-shaped one where cables go in all directions)
keyboard+mouse USBs (obviously)
Budget: Approx. 150~250 EUR

Nice-to-have

USB-A in front
Separated microphone and headphone jacks (rare feature I think)
More USBs

Ideas
I have the impression that while "standard USB" docking station brands have multiplied, quality went down or became very random... I do not even know what are considered "good brands" nowadays. I though Lenovo was a good brand, especially since one of the laptops is a Lenovo.
By searching on a very well know website that sells stuff, I'm thinking of the Wavlink UG69. But I read from another site that some consider it a poor quality brand, but most were talking about their Wi-Fi solutions, not necessarily specific docking stations.
Any opinions on this brand/model?
Any recommendations on models that match my criteria and that you have experience with?
Update
I tried the Wavlink UG69DP13-Pro but it's going straight back to sender.
On on older laptop (from work) it could not go into 60Hz at all, while the computer itself and some other docks can, on my own more recent laptop, it could go 4K@60Hz on both (two) external monitors, and even enabling HDR. But text on one of them was really bad looking. Like the letters was incomplete + JPG compression artifact. Plus it required to put one of the monitors on the ALT mode ports, but then in addition to poor image quality, image was also shifted slightly top-left or bottom-right (with Windows task bar cut in half the bottom.) Shift could disappears and image quality could be slightly increased by scaling image on that monitor to 300%... but then... what's the point of having a monitor that can display 4 times more information if the information has to take nearly 3x the space?
I read that some of these problems can't be corrected because they are inherent to DisplayLink systems (which this dock uses) and that it is sometimes advised to searches for non-DisplayLink docks. (So I add this as a requirement.)
